# Python: Possible to use multiprocessing with CV2 object trackers?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, opencv

I have the following loop in my code

```
        # Update active trackers
        timestamp = vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
        for objectID in list(trafficDict):
            ok = trafficDict[objectID].updateTracker(image, timestamp)
            if not ok:
                del trafficDict[objectID] #remove the tracker
```

I would like to send the update of each tracker (here: cv2.TrackerMedianFlow) by the new image into a separate process. However, it seems that this is not possible ("can't be pickled"). I already created a function on top-level to call the class method but the error didn't go away. I suspect CV2 doesn't allow that? Anyone that did that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trafficDict[objectID]` seems to be some custom Class instance. You didn't share how you actually communicate these two processes, but for most of the methods, as your error suggests, object being sent has to be *pickable* (serializable by `pickle` module) or it has to be a string, because only such types can actually be sent via most IPC methods.

Imagine if the type wouldn't be defined within the other process - how could it interpret the in-memory thing it just received?

If the communication is *data-oriented*, simplest solution possible is to map only the fields you need prior to sending them into a simple dictionary (note that any values within that dict will have to be pickable as well!) or prepare a JSON yourself and send a simple string via `pipe` or `socket`.